# Concatenate signal n times in Verilog

Tags: verilog

Given a signal `wire [7:0] dummy`, how can I concatenate it `n` times?

That is, is there a notation for the following:

```
{dummy, ..., dummy} // n times
```

?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is what I did to repeat and concatenate n times:

```
{n{VARIABLE}}
```

Example:

```
module concat_n(dummy,super_dummy,clk);

input [7:0] dummy;
input clk;

output [23:0] super_dummy;

wire [7:0] dummy;
reg [23:0] super_dummy;

always @(posedge clk)
  super_dummy <= {3{dummy}};

endmodule
```

Simulation:

```
   module test;

  initial begin

     $dumpfile("test.vcd");
     $dumpvars(0,test);

    dummy_in = 8'b10101111;
    #10 dummy_in = 8'b10101010;
    #10 dummy_in = 8'b11110001;
    #10 dummy_in = 8'b01010011;
    #10 dummy_in = 8'b00111100;
    #10 dummy_in = 8'b00110011;
    # 1 $finish;
  end

  reg clk = 0;
  always #1 clk = !clk;

  wire [23:0] super_dummy_out;
  reg [7:0] dummy_in; 

  concat_n concat_3 (dummy_in, super_dummy_out, clk);

  initial
     $monitor("At time %d, dummy_in = 0x%h, super_dummy_out = 0x%h ",
              $time, dummy_in, super_dummy_out);
endmodule
```

Simulation Result:
[image: Edit had to be at least 6 chars]